# Not use ">=" in java.net.URL

Tags: java, url

I want find ID of incidents greater than or equal to 100, but not working, help me!

My url:

```
URL url = new URL("https://vib.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/incidents?q=id>=100");
```

Comment: Parameter values must be url-encoded: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to be clearer about the problem you're facing - "but not working" is never sufficient detail. We don't know (just from your question) whether the code doesn't compile, whether the constructor throws an exception, or whether there's a problem when you *use* the URL.

Comment: Replace `>=` by `%3E%3D` - probably best by the mentioned URLEncoder. (I am a bit unsure on the `=` being legal.) However the question arises whether this does not allow a security breach, [SQL injection](https://www.xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with a special character appearing in your url. You need to replace `>` with `%3E`.

I think that you might still have some problems with that url, since you are putting a `=` into the parameter value. If your parser can still detect this as a value it will be fine, if not you will probably have to restructure your parameters.